# iOS - [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)] called too soon

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, animation, uiview

I have a `UIView` animation with a

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)]
```

For some reason the `animationDidStop:finished:context:` is called before the animation ends.
Any ideas? (testing on `iOS7` simulator)

code:

```
-(void)checkForAndRemoveTable {

//The animation should fade to 0 then remove itself from it's superview at the end.

if (tableViewController.view.superview != nil) {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"dismissTable" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    tableViewController.view.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


}


-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"dismissTable"]) {

     [tableViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try using block based animation. After all, Apple has recommended doing this since iOS 4.

```
if (tableViewController.view.superview != nil) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:kNilOptions animations:^{
        tableViewController.view.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [tableViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Alternatively, it is possible that this behavior is coming from misuse of the function. If for example an event occurs that calls the animation function multiple times in rapid succession, it can result in the timing of the animation callback appearing to be off. ( See comment below )

Comment: Same problem when I used this but I found the cause! It seemed I was calling the function containing my animation twice by mistake (from another function). Please update your answer with "See comments for solution". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4 and later, use the block-based animation methods. (Recommended) -> apple docs

use `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:]` method